# Android Studio + jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

При билде получаю следующее сообщение:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Users/Romario/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Users/Romario/Desktop/Yeah/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/Romario/Desktop/Yeah/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/jsoup/Connection$Base;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Что делать?
В **gradle** все прописано правильно, поток не основной!

Comment: покажите весь build.gradle. Некоторые библиотеки могут иметь зависмость от другой версии jsoup

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "steamzeppelin.com.yeah"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.2'
}

Comment: какие библиотеки лежат в папке libs?

Comment: Только jsoup больше никаких. Это тестовый проект, он только его и использует.

Comment: у тебя конфликтует jsoup в `libs` и jsoup в `compile`

Comment: На сколько знаю это обязательно нужно прописать в gradle и импортировать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалите `jsoup` из папки `libs`, раз указали `compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.2'`

При указании в виде `compile 'group_id:artifact_id:version` gradle выкачивает библиотеку из Maven repository.
При указании в виде `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` gradle берет все jar из папки.
Maven предпочтительнее, но можно и из папки только брать библиотеки

Comment: а откуда тогда студия знает где брать либу?

Comment: без этого приложение запускается и вылетает...

Comment: @headfucker обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Надо теперь разобраться почему вылетает!

Answer (score 1):

Такое впечатление что у вас в проекте несколько модулей и вы добавили `jsoup` в несколько модулей, вместо того чтобы добавить только в главный.

Comment: Вот в том то и дело, что используется только в одном, хз откуда вылезла эта ошибка. Комментировал compile строчку - приложение билдится, но вылетает.

Comment: А покажите этот самый compile

Comment: compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1' вот строка, остальное родное.